# Scenario steps are ignored

Tags: java, spring-boot, selenium-webdriver, cucumber, testng

I have created multiple login scenarios in one feature file. When I execute each scenario separately it's working fine without any errors. When I execute the login feature file only the first scenario is executed and other scenario steps are ignored.

WebDriver Library:

```
@Configuration
//@Profile("!remote")
public class WebDriverLibrary {
    @Value("${remote.url}")
    private URL remoteUrl;


    @Value("${browser}")
    private String browser;

    @Bean
    public WebDriver getChromeDriver(){
        ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
        chromeOptions.addArguments("--remote-allow-origins=*");
        return new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);
    }
```

BasePage:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;

public abstract class basePage {

    @Autowired
    private WebDriver webDriver;

    @PostConstruct
    public void InitPage(){
        PageFactory.initElements(webDriver, this);
    }
}
```

Login Feature File:

```
Feature: Login Feature
  This feature will deal with Login Functionality of the application

  Scenario: Login with Valid Credential
    Given User is on Landing Page
    And Navigate to Login Page
    And User enter email and Password
    And User click Login Button
    Then User should be navigated to Questionnaire form

  Scenario: Login with InValid Credential
    Given User is on Landing Page
    And Navigate to Login Page
    And User enter email and Password
    And User click Login Button
    Then User should get error message

  Scenario: Navigating to Login Page through SignUp Page
    Given User is on Landing Page
    And Navigate to SignUp Page
    And Click on Login link
    And User enter email and Password
    And User click Login Button
    Then User should get error message

  Scenario: Navigating to Login Page through Login button from NavBar
    Given User is on Landing Page
    And Click on Login button in NavBar
    And User enter email and Password
    And User click Login Button
    Then User should get error message
```

I created a step definition file through "create all step definition" option.

Login Step Definition:

```
public class LoginSteps {
    @Autowired
    private WebDriver webDriver;

    @Autowired
    private LandingPage landingPage;

    @Autowired
    private LoginPage loginPage;

    @Autowired
    private SignUpPage signUpPage;

    @Autowired
    private QuestionnairePage questionnairePage;

    @Given("User is on Landing Page")
    public void userIsOnLandingPage() {
        Assert.assertTrue(landingPage.btnGetStarted.isDisplayed());
    }

    @And("Navigate to Login Page")
    public void navigateToLoginPage() {
        webDriver.navigate().to("http://localhost:4200/login");
//        landingPage.btnGetStarted.click();
    }

    @And("User enter email and Password")
    public void userEnterEmailAndPassword() {
        loginPage.LoginDetails();
    }

    @And("User click Login Button")
    public void userClickLoginButton() {
        loginPage.btnLogininLoginPage.click();
    }

    @Then("User should be navigated to Questionnaire form")
    public void userShouldBeNavigatedToQuestionnaireForm() {
        System.out.println("User Navigated to Questionnaire page");
//        Assert.assertTrue(questionnairePage.qusTitle.getText().contentEquals("Questionnaire Form"));
    }

    @Then("User should get error message")
    public void userShouldGetErrorMessage() {
        System.out.println("Error Message");
    }

    @And("Navigate to SignUp Page")
    public void navigateToSignUpPage() {
        webDriver.navigate().to("http://localhost:4200/Signup");
//        landingPage.btnsignUpForFree.click();
    }

    @And("Click on Login link")
    public void clickOnLoginLink() {
        webDriver.navigate().to("http://localhost:4200/login");
//        signUpPage.lnkLogin.click();
    }

    @And("Click on Login button in NavBar")
    public void clickOnLoginButtonInNavBar() {
        webDriver.navigate().to("http://localhost:4200/login");
//        landingPage.btnNavBarLogin.click();
    }


}
```

Cucumber Hook file:

```
public class Hooks {
    @Autowired
    private WebDriver webDriver;

    @Value("${app.url}")
    private String appUrl;

    @Before
    public void InitializeTest(Scenario scenario){
        webDriver.navigate().to(appUrl);
        webDriver.manage().window().maximize();
    }

    @After
    public void TearDownTest(Scenario scenario){
        if(scenario.isFailed()){
            System.out.println(scenario.getName());
        }
        webDriver.quit();
    }
}
```

TestRunner:

```
@CucumberOptions(
        features = {"src/test/java/com/ksupwlt/stepcounttracker/features"},
        glue = "com.ksupwlt.stepcounttracker.steps"
)
public class TestRunner extends AbstractTestNGCucumberTests {
```

Without using the webdriver.quit() the browser is closed. is it necessary to add the @After?
Test Report:

Login with InValid Credential
1.95 spassedBefore
16 msfailedUser is on Landing Page
Step failedorg.openqa.selenium.NoSuchSessionException: Session ID is null. Using WebDriver after calling quit()?
Build info: version: '4.1.2', revision: '9a5a329c5a'
System info: host: 'DESKTOP-55B4PJT', ip: '192.168.1.66', os.name: 'Windows 11', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '19.0.2'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Command: [null, findElement {using=xpath, value=//button[contains(text(),'Get Started')]}]
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: false, browserName: chrome, browserVersion: 111.0.5563.65, chrome: {chromedriverVersion: 110.0.5481.77 (65ed616c6e8e..., userDataDir: C:\Users\santh\AppData\Loca...}, goog:chromeOptions: {debuggerAddress: localhost:55962}, javascriptEnabled: true, networkConnectionEnabled: false, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platform: WINDOWS, platformName: WINDOWS, proxy: Proxy(), se:cdp: ws://localhost:55962/devtoo..., se:cdpVersion: 111.0.5563.65, setWindowRect: true, strictFileInteractability: false, timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000}, unhandledPromptBehavior: dismiss and notify, webauthn:extension:credBlob: true, webauthn:extension:largeBlob: true, webauthn:virtualAuthenticators: true}
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:145)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.invokeExecute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:167)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:142)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:558)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ElementLocation$ElementFinder$2.findElement(ElementLocation.java:162)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ElementLocation.findElement(ElementLocation.java:60)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:382)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:374)
at org.openqa.selenium.support.pagefactory.DefaultElementLocator.findElement(DefaultElementLocator.java:70)
at org.openqa.selenium.support.pagefactory.internal.LocatingElementHandler.invoke(LocatingElementHandler.java:39)
at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy118.isDisplayed(Unknown Source)
at com.ksupwlt.stepcounttracker.steps.LoginSteps.userIsOnLandingPage(LoginSteps.java:35)
at ?.User is on Landing Page(file:///C:/Sandy/Spring_2023/Capstone/KSU%20Patient%20Weight%20Loss%20Tracker/src/test/java/com/ksupwlt/stepcounttracker/features/Login.feature:12)
0 msignoredNavigate to Login Page
0 msignoredUser enter email and Password
0 msignoredUser click Login Button
0 msignoredUser should get error message
238 mspassedAfter

[image: Screenshot of error message]

[image: Screenshot for reference]

Comment: You're using Spring, so your autowired `WebDriver` is a singleton shared between all scenarios. Have a look at https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/tree/main/cucumber-spring#sharing-state-between-steps. You can change the `TestUserInformation` to hold a webdriver that you create before each test.

Comment: Can I add the user information for all scenarios (i mean for a signup, login ,and some other form) in one TestUserInformation file or do I need to create separate test user information.

Comment: It didn't work same error exists saying org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchSessionException: Session ID is null. Using WebDriver after calling quit()?

Comment: It's hard to say "what didn't work". You've not really explained how you created your webdriver or what you've changed now. Perhaps you can start a new question. And it is also worth starting with a small toy project to help you debug things before you ask that question. See: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Sorry for that. Updated the question

Comment: You're still creating the webdriver as a singleton `@Bean public WebDriver getChromeDriver()`.

Comment: We need to use the webdriver as a  singleton to access across the classes right?. what will be the solution.

Comment: You can manually create and destroy the webdriver and put it into a scenario scoped holder class (like the `TestUserInformation` example) or use the scenario scope annotation on the bean declaration, though in that case you may have to check how to close the driver when the scenario scope ends.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Added pageScope file and changed the @component to @pageScope in the pages file(login page). It working fine and also I removed the webdriver.quit(). browser was closed by the selenium as soon as the test is done.

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.config.ConfigurableBeanFactory;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Scope;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import java.lang.annotation.*;

@Component
@Scope(ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
@Documented
@Target({ElementType.TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface PageScope {
}
```